# Maven surefire plugin not running tests after migrating from Spock 1.2 to 2.0-M2

Tags: maven, spock, java-11, maven-surefire-plugin

Working setup -

```
Spock older version - 1.2-groovy-2.4
jdk version - 8
Maven surefire plugin version - 2.22.0
Maven version - 3.5.0
```

Migrated setup -

```
Spock version - 2.0-M2-groovy-2.5
jdk version - 11
Maven surefire plugin version - 3.0.0-M4
Maven version - 3.6.3
```

MCVE - https://github.com/ajaydivakaran/spock_spike

The intent of upgrading Spock was to make it compatible with jdk 11.
The test class files are present in the target/test-classes folder but are not run.

Comment: Please show your pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise I've updated the description to include a link to the POM file

Comment: Even with jdk8 this issue exists. Spock 1.2 and 1.3 versions work fine. It is only when I change it to 2.0 does it not run from the command line. Tried with 2.0-M2-groovy-3.0 too but no luck.

Comment: Actually your Surefire (3.0.0-M4) and Failsafe (2.22.2) versions are different, which is a bit strange but basically both versions should be okay because Spock 2 needs at least Surefire/Failsafe 2.22.0+ in order to work. What I do not see, though, is your JUnit version. Please note that Spock 2 ist based on JUnit 5 Jupiter and implements its own engine on that platform. If you could post a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, maybe I can take a look. Furthermore, what in Spock do you want to make "compatible with Java 11"? Please explain.

Comment: @kriegaex With Spock 1.2 and jdk 11 I was getting "does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object getProperty(java.lang.String)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject" errors. Upgrading Spock to 2.0 fixed these errors.

Comment: You did not reply anything to the main question about JUnit version I raised. Please elaborate on that.

Comment: @kriegaex I included junit-jupiter-api and junit-jupiter-engine version 5.6.2 but still no luck.

Comment: I cannot do anything for you without the MCVE. Please follow the link above in order to find out what MCVE means. Thank you.

Comment: @kriegaex I've updated the description to include a link to the MCVE.

Comment: In the MCVE the java test gets identified but not the groovy test.

Comment: In the MVCE if I change the test to use the JUnit5 annotations and include the dependencies I notice that no tests are run. Commenting out the spock and groovy dependencies then picks up the JUnit5 test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Variant A: JUnit 4 + Spock 2 (Groovy 2.5)

In your Git repository I saw that your JUnit test imports `org.junit.Test` from JUnit 4 which you use as an undeclared transitive dependency used by Spock Core. For this you need the JUnit vintage engine or otherwise after you fixed running the Spock tests, the JUnit tests will no longer run.

If you name your unit tests according to [Surefire convention](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes), i.e. `*Test`, `*Tests`, `*TestCase`, `Test*` instead of the Spock convention `*Spec`, you also do not need to configure an `<execution>` section with extra includes. I just deleted it because your sample Spock test was named `*Test` already.

The same also applies to [integration tests with Maven Failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) where the naming convention is `*IT`, `*ITCase`, `IT*`, if you want to add Failsafe later.

The Maven Build Helper plugin is also superfluous, so I removed it.

Last but not least, Spock 2 depends on `groovy` as a normal import, no longer on `groovy-all` as a `<type>pom</type>` import.

With the following changes your tests run nicely:

```
--- pom.xml (revision 35c8e179569a7b45d48729d6cecf8170d02c8ed2)
+++ pom.xml (date 1589849467265)
@@ -25,6 +25,8 @@
         <groovy.version>2.5.11</groovy.version>
         <spock.version>2.0-M2-groovy-2.5</spock.version>

+        <junit.version>5.6.2</junit.version>
+
     </properties>

     <build>
@@ -64,45 +66,8 @@
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
-                <executions>
-                    <execution>
-                        <id>default-test</id>
-                        <phase>test</phase>
-                        <goals>
-                            <goal>test</goal>
-                        </goals>
-                        <configuration>
-                            <includes>
-                                <include>**/*Test.class</include>
-                                <include>**/*Spec.class</include>
-                                <include>**/*Should.class</include>
-                            </includes>
-                        </configuration>
-                    </execution>
-                </executions>
-            </plugin>
-
-            <plugin>
-                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
-                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
-                <version>${build-helper-maven-plugin.version}</version>
-                <executions>
-                    <execution>
-                        <id>add-test-source</id>
-                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
-                        <goals>
-                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
-                        </goals>
-                        <configuration>
-                            <sources>
-                                <source>src/test/groovy</source>
-                            </sources>
-                        </configuration>
-                    </execution>
-                </executions>
             </plugin>

-
         </plugins>
     </build>

@@ -110,13 +75,18 @@

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
-            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
+            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
             <version>${groovy.version}</version>
-            <type>pom</type>
+            <scope>test</scope>
+        </dependency>
+
+        <dependency>
+            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
+            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
+            <version>${junit.version}</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>

-
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
```

### Variant B: JUnit 5 + Spock 2 (Groovy 2.5)

Most of what I said above still applies, only you need to switch from the JUnit 5 Vintage engine to the normal JUnit 5 Jupiter engine. Then you need to adjust the import in your JUnit test to `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`.

The diff to your project looks like this:

```
--- src/test/java/me/spike/SubtractionTest.java (revision 35c8e179569a7b45d48729d6cecf8170d02c8ed2)
+++ src/test/java/me/spike/SubtractionTest.java (date 1589850279261)
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 package me.spike;

-import org.junit.Test;
+import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

 import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

--- pom.xml (revision 35c8e179569a7b45d48729d6cecf8170d02c8ed2)
+++ pom.xml (date 1589850279254)
@@ -25,6 +25,8 @@
         <groovy.version>2.5.11</groovy.version>
         <spock.version>2.0-M2-groovy-2.5</spock.version>

+        <junit.version>5.6.2</junit.version>
+
     </properties>

     <build>
@@ -64,45 +66,8 @@
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
-                <executions>
-                    <execution>
-                        <id>default-test</id>
-                        <phase>test</phase>
-                        <goals>
-                            <goal>test</goal>
-                        </goals>
-                        <configuration>
-                            <includes>
-                                <include>**/*Test.class</include>
-                                <include>**/*Spec.class</include>
-                                <include>**/*Should.class</include>
-                            </includes>
-                        </configuration>
-                    </execution>
-                </executions>
-            </plugin>
-
-            <plugin>
-                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
-                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
-                <version>${build-helper-maven-plugin.version}</version>
-                <executions>
-                    <execution>
-                        <id>add-test-source</id>
-                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
-                        <goals>
-                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
-                        </goals>
-                        <configuration>
-                            <sources>
-                                <source>src/test/groovy</source>
-                            </sources>
-                        </configuration>
-                    </execution>
-                </executions>
             </plugin>

-
         </plugins>
     </build>

@@ -110,13 +75,24 @@

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
-            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
+            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
             <version>${groovy.version}</version>
-            <type>pom</type>
+            <scope>test</scope>
+        </dependency>
+
+        <dependency>
+            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
+            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
+            <version>${junit.version}</version>
+            <scope>test</scope>
+        </dependency>
+        <dependency>
+            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
+            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
+            <version>${junit.version}</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>

-
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
```

### Dependency conflicts

On a side note, I found some dependency version conflicts in your project, e.g. Groovy versions 2.5.11 used by you vs. 2.5.8 used by Spock or JUnit 4.13 used by JUnit Jupiter vs. 4.12 used by Spock. Inside JUnit 5 the vintage engine also uses another platform engine than Spock Core.

In IntelliJ IDEA your dependency graph looks like this (red are conflicts):

[image: Dependency graph before clean-up]

With a dependency management section you can fix the conflicts and also simplify the dependency imports in your modules to not having to use the centrally managed version numbers or scopes anymore, as long as you do not wish to modify them for whatever reason.

It would look like this for your project in variant B (JUnit 5):

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
                <version>${groovy.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spock.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Now the dependency graph looks like this:

[image: Dependency graph after clean-up]

---

**Update:** After a short while, when trying to use more of Spock, such as class mocking with CGLIB or ByteBuddy, you will notice that it is not a good idea to use Groovy-Eclipse batch compiler 3.0 with Groovy 2.5. You always should use a matching version, as we have just discussed in [my answer to your next question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61910484/1082681). So you want to be careful and keep Groovy compiler and Groovy version in sync, in this case:

```xml
<groovy-eclipse-batch.version>2.5.11-01</groovy-eclipse-batch.version>
```

Comment: Spock 2 depends on groovy as a normal import, no longer on groovy-all as a <type>pom</type> import seems to be the key change here when only using Spock tests. After making this change my Spock tests started running.

Comment: Why do these tests run fine via IntelliJ and only fail to be identified when using maven to run them? Is IntelliJ using another mechanism to satisfy these dependencies?

Comment: IntelliJ does not help you in a Continuous Integration environment. Yes, IntelliJ imports from Maven but has its own mechanism too, unless you configure it to delegate all build actions to Maven. BTW, the "Groovy as normal import" thing fixes Maven finding the Spock tests, but not the JUnit tests. You want both, you said. So you got to fix both. I would not have written so much if it was that simple.

Comment: My setup includes both so your detailed answer has helped a lot.

Comment: I know its not part of the original question but could you shed some light as to why running Spock and Junit tests from IntelliJ worked fine?

Comment: **Update:** I amended my answer by infofmation about matching compiler version for Groovy runtime version used, so people reading this one also see it, not just readers of your other question.