# Run JUnit5 and Spock in maven lifecycle

Tags: java, maven, junit, spock, java-14

I want to run spock 2.0-M2-groovy-3.0 and junit 5.6.2 test in java 14 during maven test.
My pom looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
        <guava-version>29.0-jre</guava-version>
        <spock-version>2.0-M2-groovy-3.0</spock-version>
        <spring-boot-admin-version>2.2.3</spring-boot-admin-version>
        <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.7.0.1746</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.5</jacoco.version>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
        <junit-platform.version>1.6.2</junit-platform.version>
        <jupiter.version>5.6.2</jupiter.version>
        <spock.version>2.0-M2-groovy-3.0</spock.version>
        <gmavenplus-plugin.version>1.9.0</gmavenplus-plugin.version>
        <maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.22.0</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
        <groovy.version>3.0.3</groovy.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-admin-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gmavenplus-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addSources</goal>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <testSources>
                        <testSource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </testSource>
                    </testSources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                    <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
                    <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
                    <output>file</output>
                    <append>true</append>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>*MethodAccess</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

and if I run

```
mvn clean install
```

only JUnit test is running, but if I change maven-surefire-plugin like:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

spock and junit test are running together but I get warning:

```
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | WARNING:                                                                      |
 | The junit-platform-surefire-provider has been deprecated and is scheduled to  |
 | be removed in JUnit Platform 1.4. Please use the built-in support in Maven    |
 | Surefire >= 2.22.0 instead.                                                   |
 | » https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible achive running spock and junit test during maven lifecycle without above warning?

Comment: First remove the surefire provider from maven-surefire-plugin configuration cause it is not needed or even worse simply wrong. Furthermore: Why do you have configured vintage of JUnit Jupiter? BTW: Just use `mvn clean verify` and not `mvn clean install`

Comment: I checked and only junit test ran

Comment: I recommend Marcin's solution because you started with GMavenPlus already. But if you are interested in a solution where you can directly use Maven Compiler plugin and the normal Maven lifecycle, you may want to try Groovy-Eclipse instead. Just lately some questions came up about it, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61881671/1082681) I answered. The Spock community mostly seems to use GMavenPlus because that is what the maintainers also use and support with sample projects. I always use Groovy-Eclipse and am quite happy with it, though.

Answer (score 3):

First, upgrade maven-surefire-plugin to 3.0.0(-M4) which runs JUnit Platform (JUnit 5) tests by default. Then it should be enough to just add spock-core 2.0 dependency. Sample [working project](https://github.com/szpak/code-examples-and-poc/blob/master/spock2-migration-gradle-maven/pom.xml) from [my blog post](https://blog.solidsoft.pl/2020/01/02/migrating-spock-1.3-tests-to-spock-2.0/) treating about Spock 1 -> 2 migration (of course Groovy 3.0 is recommended to use).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>info.solidsoft.blog.spock2-migration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock2-migration-maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spock.version>2.0-M2-groovy-2.5</spock.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5.11</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include> <!-- Yes, .java extension -->
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include> <!-- Just in case of having also "normal" JUnit tests -->
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Required only to use JUnit 4 @Rule/@ClassRule -->
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Surefire 2.22.2 also works nicely with JUnit 5 and Spock 2, if you (the OP, not Marcin) feel hesitant to use a milestone release, but I also used Surefire/Failsafe 3 milestones before and had no issues other than a console logging problem with a Java agent, but that has been fixed this week and is also broken in Surefire 2.x anyway.